# Multithreading - Calling a function after a specific time by each thread

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, signals, alarm

I want all of the threads (in a multithreaded C code running on Linux) to call a function after a specific time . I tried *alarm()*. It is not thread safe: *[Only one SIGALRM generation can be scheduled in this manner. If the SIGALRM signal has not yet been generated, the call shall result in rescheduling the time at which the SIGALRM signal is generated](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/alarm.html)*.
Is there any way to implement such functionality and guarantee that the thread would call the function and leave its current task at that time?

Comment: What sort of time frame are you talking about. How many threads and what are they doing. You can get close to this maybe, but guarantee it, not really.

Comment: The threads are running some openmp tasks. I want to interrupt their current work and make them do something else and then come back to their work. About 100 threads. I can think about the exact timing later. Is there any way to do so? how much close?

Comment: Is there a need to interrupt them after an exact period of time? Maybe a counter for "work done" will suffice.

Comment: @CongXu: could you please explain more? How?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/8dbQ5PY8

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't solve my problem. In OpenMP, you cannot estimate how much work a thread has done. That is exactly, what I want to call a function after a delay.

Comment: You have a 100 threads running on top of a working system. That means unless you've built a 256 core transputer array, some of them will swapped be out. So no you can't guarantee they will all do something at the same time. Well not unless you define exact same time as some times next Wednesday. You can guarantee the next thing they do when they look at what they have to do is the next is the thing you want them to, when they can.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson: Okay, I think the focus has been changed. some times next Wednesday is what I want. I want to guarantee that they will all call the function. The data structure inside the function is protected with a lock. By "the same time", I mean one by one giving up their work and wait on the lock. That part is trivial. But how to implement and call such a function

Answer (score 0):

Do you have an array with all the `pthread_t`s of the other threads?  If so, iterate on the array and use `pthread_kill` to send the signal to the other threads.

You can do this in the main thread, or in a separate thread.

Be careful that there's not much that you can safely do in a signal handler.  No I/O except for `write`, in particular.